# Updating other modules schema when creating custom module

Tags: 7

I need to add a information to a content types within my module. Generally, is it good practise to update `node_type` schema or is it better to create my own and join it to the `node_type` via primary key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of the `hook_schema_alter` to update entity schema of existing schema's.

```
function YOURMODULE_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  // Add field to existing schema.
  $schema['users']['fields']['timezone_id'] = array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
    'description' => 'Per-user timezone configuration.',
  );
}
```

Comment: It depends on the complexity of your information you need to add on your content type. If it is 1 piece of content, you generally alter the existing schema. On the other hand, if you have a lot of extra information to store, you create your own schema. It is also your job to load / save / ... the extra data which requires a lot more development if you go for option 2.